# How to add link to Jenkins side-panel?

Tags: java, plugins, jenkins

Can anybody help me with adding link to Jenkins CI ? I've implemented Action interface, created jelly.index in the same package under resources. What are my next steps?

Please, help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a link to the main page, look at RootAction and do not forget to put @Extension tag for your class. The jelly file should be index.jelly, not jelly.index.

You can also take a look how other plugins do it:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JQS+Monitoring+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM2Job+Plugin

cheers